# Fitting a Bezier curve between two parallel lines

Tags: polynomials, curves

I have Two parallel lines, I want to create from one line to another using a cubic Bezier curve (S shaped basically), I'm free to pick any start point and end point. But the constraint is this path should be optimally shortest, also another constraint is I don't want the curves with too much curvature, I just want to switch to the other parallel line smoothly without creating too much curvy path. My question is how to pick start and end point? for having such a curve?

I'm considering Bezier curve would be best for this with my very little research

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show your research or other efforts at solving.

Comment: The shortest Bezier curve connecting the two lines will be a perpendicular line segment between them (yes, that does not qualify as a Bezier curve, but it is the limit that the Bezier curves approach as they get shorter). As they become shorter, their maximum curvature increases to $\infty$ (the two right corners in the perpendicular line). You say you want to limit curvature, but didn't specify what that limit would be. Whatever that is, the shortest cubic Bezier curve will be right at that limit.

Comment: Do you want the connecting curve to join smoothly with the two lines (same tangent direction)?